# Chrome plugin to upload image directly from clipboard?

Tags: chrome, clipboard

I often have this workflow when I need to upload a picture to Trello (or other webapps)

- I have a picture open in photoshop with a selection
- Control+Shift+C to copy the selection to clipboard
- File -> New
- Paste
- Save
- Browse to some temporary location
- Press the upload button on the web form
- Go to the previous temporary location
- Select the file

Is there any Chrome plugin where you can directly upload from clipboard instead of always having to select a file?

This would essentially save step 3 to 9.

I'm looking for a Windows solution.

Thanks!

Comment: At least for [Imgur](http://imgur.com/), you don't need a plugin: just click on their "unload" link and Ctrl+V your clipboard content. If your other sites can use Imgur links (like SE does), that would let you skip steps 3-9, and instead you'd 3) open a bookmark in your browser, 4) click upload, 5) Ctrl-V + submit, 6) right-click the image to get it's source URL. Might be a work-around until good answers turn up :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Copy-n-Paste: Image Upload Simplified](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/copy-n-paste-image-upload/bnmdedmhngbeofnafobjmcihealecgnf)**. I do the same thing with Photoshop too, so I've made an extension to do exactly this! Give it a try

*Late response and still isn't a Chrome feature. Hopefully this helps newcomers*

[image]